# Using VBA to extract data from within a Javascript function source

Tags: javascript, html, function, vba

Using VBA, is it possible to extract only the JavaScript function text from a webpage formatted similar to the one below?

I started using .innerText but I am concerned about parsing thru the massive amount of data that may be populated on the page above the JavaScript. I can execute the JavaScript and then extract value when it is stored but then I have to deal with the 'Save As' window. This is an internal company webpage so I cannot provide the link.

At the end of the day, all I need is the filename "save.F1234567890" (they always start with "save.F" but the numbers change everytime the website is run). I'll then use the filename and URLDownloadToFile function to save to my computer as I have successfully used in the past.

Thanks in advance!

```
<input name="stuff" type=HIDDEN value="999" >
<input type=hidden name=orgn value=.>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function setThis(this)      
 {     
 for (i=0;i<document.forms[0].set_this.length;i++)   
   { 
     if (document.forms[0].set_this[i].checked==true)     
      setthis= document.forms[0].set_this[i].value;     
  }                                      
    if (setthis == 1 )       
        { document.forms[0].filename.value = "save.F1234567890";      
          document.forms[0]._program.value = "download.excel"; }   
      else                                       
        if (setthis == 2 )       
          { document.forms[0].filename.value = "save.MB1234567890";    
            document.forms[0]._program.value = "download.excel"; }    
      else                                       
        if (setthis == 3 )       
           document.forms[0]._program.value = "download.savereport";    

      else                                       
        if (setthis == 4 )       
        { document.forms[0].filename.value = "save.E1234567890";      
           document.forms[0]._program.value = "download.process"; }   

      document.forms[0].submit();       
 }          
</SCRIPT>        
<TABLE BORDER=1>
<tr><td><input name="set_this" type=radio value="3" checked >Save Parameters. <input type=text size=8 name="logon" VALUE="USERNAME"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input name="set_this" type=radio value="1"  >Download data as .CSV file  </td></tr>
<tr><td >  
<input type=button value="Submit" onClick="javascript:setThis(); ">
</td></tr><tr><td >
<input type="button" value="Previous Screen" onClick="history.back()">
</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: using VBA ? Visual Basic for Application ?

Comment: Yes. I am launching all of the automation from Access 2010.

Comment: Will there always only be one "save.F"?

Comment: If you want to start with just the text of that function you can use: `s = IE.document.parentWindow.setThis`

Comment: @TimWilliams I am attempting to use a combination of your answer and Blackhawk's to minimize the total string size. Your solution works at only getting the function but my code continues to change "setThis" to "setthis" even after I removed all of the modules and opened a fresh one. I can't seem to find the declaration that is driving the case change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I wouldn't recommend a Regular Expression for parsing through a webpage, but what you want is so specific it might be the most efficient way.  Assuming that there will only be one "save.F", you can use the following to find the string.

You can add the RegExp library to your VBA project by clicking Tools ---> References and check the box next to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5".

```
Public Function GetSaveName(strHTML) As String
    Dim oRegExp As RegExp
    Dim oMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim oMatch As Match

    Set oRegExp = New RegExp
    With oRegExp
        .Global = True
        .Multiline = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = """save.F[^""]*?"""
        Set oMatches = .Execute(strHTML)
    End With

    Set oMatch = oMatches.Item(0)

    GetSaveName = oMatch.Value
End Function
```

Comment: The answer you suggested works if I pull the innerText of the webpage and run it thru your function. Do you recommend that method or a different one?

Comment: @Mars_Out there are a couple other ways you might do it.  First, use the HTML DOM to find that particular chunk of Javascript and search through that specifically instead of the whole page.  Second, you might even find a method of running it to get your value, like scripting SHDocVw.InternetExplorer or loading the innertext of the Script tag into JScript.

Comment: I used Tim's recommendation which grabbed only the function's text then I cut thru text using your recommendation and it worked out very well. Thank you both!